# CSS 2 Floating Div's Inside Container Full Height w/ Image

Tags: html, css

I have a container thats 900px wide with 2 floating divs inside. I need to make column 2 background full height and dependent to the image to the left. The text in column 2 also needs to be vertically centered, again based on image height.

https://jsfiddle.net/rj5o6n79/1/

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="col span_2_of_3 content">
      <img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" />
   </div>
   <div class="col span_1_of_3 box2">
      This is column 2
   </div>  
   <div style="clear:both;"></div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jQuery` to get the `height` of the left `div`

```
var leftDivHeight = $('.span_2_of_3').height();
$('.span_1_of_3').css('height',leftDivHeight);
```

then wrap the content of your `inner div` to another `div`

```
<div class="col span_1_of_3 box2">
    <div class='innerContent'> This is column 2 </div> <!-- added div -->
</div>
```

then add this css to vertically center your inner `div`

```
.innerContent{
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/71dsfrk5/4/)**

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seems it won't work for multiple testimonials. Here is my jsfiddle... https://jsfiddle.net/71dsfrk5/5/

Comment: @user1628845, like this? https://jsfiddle.net/wytndhyx/1/  .but there's a big  space between the two divs..  I think it would be easy if you use `display: table` for your `div`

Comment: Yeah why is the white space appearing? Would using the display table mean taking away away progress?

Comment: @user1628845, since you're using class so you need to specify on what index it belongs.. https://jsfiddle.net/wytndhyx/2/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```css
body { margin:0; padding:0; }

.wrapper { border:1px solid green; width:900px; margin:0px auto; }

.content {
    width: 100%; /* or whatever is required */
    text-align: center; /* ensures the image is always in the h-middle */
    overflow: hidden; /* hide the cropped portion */
}

img {
    position: relative; /* allows repositioning */
   /*left: 100%;   move the whole width of the image to the right */
    /* margin-left: -200%; magic! */
    float:left;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
 display: block;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

.box { background-color: #ccc; }
.box2 { background-color: red; }
/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before,
.group:after {
 content:"";
 display:table;
}
.group:after {
 clear:both;
}
.group {
    zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */
}

/*  GRID OF THREE  */
.span_3_of_3 {
 width: 100%;
}
.span_2_of_3 {
 width: 66.1%;
}
.span_1_of_3 {
 width: 33.8%;
    height: 400px;
}
.content {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  text-align:left;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

<div class="col span_2_of_3 content">
 <img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" />
 </div>
 <div class="col span_1_of_3 box2">
        <div class="content">
 This is column 2
         </div>
 </div>
    
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: the OP wants this: *"I need to make column 2 background full height and dependent to the image to the left"*,  so the height of column 2 must be dynamic..

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I wanted to stay away from setting a height under the class .span_1_of_3 as I need to have multiple testimonials with different heights. https://jsfiddle.net/71dsfrk5/5/

Answer (score 0):

I think, I have more or less found what you are looking for. Though the second column isn't full height it is vertically centered and just as big as it needs to be.

```css
.wrapper {
            width: 900px;
            border: 1px solid #000000;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .col img{
            display: block;
        }

        .content {
            vertical-align: middle;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .box2 {
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="col span_2_of_3 content">
        <img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_3 box2">
        This is column 2
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I have a solution of your problem checkout this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Navtosh/pknpsh7u/), I think it's working for you. Here is the code:

```css
body { margin:0; padding:0; }

.wrapper {     
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  /* background: #f00; */
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;}

.content {
  width: 100%; /* or whatever is required */
  text-align: center; /* ensures the image is always in the h-middle */
  overflow: hidden; /* hide the cropped portion */
}

img {
  position: relative; /* allows repositioning */
  left: 100%; /* move the whole width of the image to the right */
  margin-left: -200%; /* magic! */
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

.box { background-color: #ccc; }
.box2 { background-color: red; }
/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before,
.group:after {
  content:"";
  display:table;
}
.group:after {
  clear:both;
}
.group {
  zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */
}

/*  GRID OF THREE  */
.span_3_of_3 {
  width: 100%;
}
.span_2_of_3 {
  width: 66.1%;
}
.span_1_of_3 {
  width: 33.8%;
}
td{ background:#000; color:#fff;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="col span_2_of_3 content">
    <img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="col span_1_of_3 box2">
    This is column 2
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```